# Triggering custom flows in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I can [define custom flows](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_admin/#_authentication-flows) in Keycloak and replace standard flows with them.

Is it possible to define a custom flow and trigger it manually, via link? It would be useful for example for extending user self management.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a client and then override some of the authentication flows for this particular client. The feature is not documented yet and somewhat hidden at the bottom of the first client administration tab:

[image]

If you are triggering the authentication flow from a specific application, this solution should work for you.

Possibly there is also a link to trigger it. I just don't know but would also be interested in learning about it – in particular a link to trigger a specific registration flow.